# How to detect a click in specified area with AutoHotkey?

Tags: click, autohotkey, detect, area

I'm looking for a solution on how to detect a mouse click in a specified area of window when using AutoHotkey.
Let's say I would like to detect click in the area of coordinates x 100 y100, x120 y120.
Any ideas or solutions would be highly appreciated, thank you!

edit 2: I just answered this question with a working code below.

Comment: I tried nothing before. Out if the blue I caught an idea, and it works properly:

~LButton::
MouseGetPos, x,y
if (x > 800 and x < 1500  and y < 600 and y > 200)
 MouseMove, 1000, 400
return

Thx for encouraging me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code worked for me correctly:

```
~LButton::
MouseGetPos, x,y
if (x > 800 and x < 1500  and y < 600 and y > 200)
    MouseMove, 1000, 400
return
```

where 800, 1500, 600 and 200 are boundaries of desired area. If clicked inside it, the cursor will be moved out to a position 1000, 400.